# threejs merge plane geometries or create a texture from multiple images

Tags: three.js

I have a set of plane geometries, each having a their own texture from a url. At any point during navigation(zoom/pan) the container (THREE.Object3D) contains 26 plane geometries. How will i merge them to a single big plane so that i could apply a heighmap for all tiles in the merge geometry.

Or How could I get all the texture from the 36 images.(currently as a map property for MeshPhongMaterial) in to a single geometry?

**EDIT:**

Currently I create a Big geometry as suggested by `Dainel`. and put a texture to the geometry which is a combined texture of a set of images via canvas.

```
context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
var img = Image();
img.src = url //url of the texture tile
context.drawImage(img,xpos, ypos);
```

This is done or every images. Each image have a url, xpos, ypos. Images are preloaded and after loading every images a callback is called which creates the geometry(plane) and add texture from the canvas.

```
  var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas); 
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map : texture });
```

var geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(canvas.width, canvas.height, 57, 40);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
scene.add( mesh );

also i update the z vertex of geometry with the height values.

Comment: Look at `THREE.GeometryUtils.merge()`. Read the source so you understand what it does. See if it helps you, and then reformulate your question if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [terrainLoader](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/10/terrain-building-with-threejs.html) class for threejs and canvas texture I was able to acheive

```
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, mywidth / myheight, 0.01, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 240);

  scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xeeeeee));

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(mywidth, myheight);

  var group = new THREE.Object3D();

  var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
  canvas.width = mywidth;
  canvas.height = myheight;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  /* adjust width, height, segments based on height data;*/

  /* create a plane geometry */
  var geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(800, 692, 40, 55);

  /* 
  read height values from .bin file uing terrainLoader 
  and update the Z values of the plane 
   */

  heightdata = 'assets/heightmap.bin'; 
  terrainLoader.load(heightdata, function(data) {

    /* bin file generated from USGS SRTM tile */ 
    for (var i = 0, l = geom.vertices.length ; i < l; i++) {
      geom.vertices[i].z =   data[i] / 200; /*simple scale */
    }

    geom.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  });

   /* 
   create a texture from canvas created above with width and height
   of the of the scene. This is to be careful as the size of texture 
   image may not be the same but as same ratio as height map. 
   Atleast for my case it was the situation. But geometry width and 
   texture width are in same ratio. So that i need a small array of 
   heightmap from bin but a much bigger texture 
   */   

  var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas); 
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map : texture });
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
  group.add( mesh );
  scene.add(group);
```

Now to draw multiple images to canvas check this page

I will just duplicate the code from [HTML5 Canvas Image Loader Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/)

```
   function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        // get num of sources
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }

      var sources = {
        darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
        yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
      };
```

You can call the loadImages function after updating the Plane geometry from heightmap in above code.

```
 loadImages(sources, function(images) {

        //context = context of the texture put in threejs texture

        context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 100, 30, 200, 137);
        context.drawImage(images.yoda, 350, 55, 93, 104);
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

u may create one "big" plane and apply a merged texture to it

or u could manually set the vertex Y-values of each plane to match the corresponding part of the height map. so u have a set of separate planes that all share the same "base" height map.

regards,
daniel

Comment: how do I merge textures? or how to share same height map?. remember heightmap span on multiple planes in this case

Comment: simply create one "big" image draw all single patches to it and create a texture of it.

Comment: u don't need to "merge" the geometry of all planes. u need to adjust each vertex height component(Y) of the plane geometry to match the evaluated height of your height map.

Comment: you mean to draw each texture into a canvas and use the imagedata? will that slows down the rendering?. BTW, I am still not clear with adjusting each vertex height component. Currently i update the geometry.vertices[i].z to make the height map

Comment: yep that's what i mean - set the .z value to the corresponding height map value. 
geometry.vertices[i].z = highmap.getHeight(geometry.vertices[i].x * planeOffsetX, geometry.vertices[i].y*planeOffsetY);

Comment: what is highmap here ?

Comment: currently i put all the images in a canvas and use a big plane geometry with a texture created from canvas. updated the question. see above.